# bonobo git server windows authentication

Tags: windows, authentication, bonobo

I'm install a new bonobo git server on my os windows 10. These my configuration structure for windows authentication :

```
 <!-- <add key="AuthenticationProvider" value="Cookies" /> -->
 <add key="AuthenticationProvider" value="Windows" />
 <add key="ImportWindowsAuthUsersAsAdmin" value="true" />
 <!--<add key="AuthenticationProvider" value="Federation" />-->
 <add key="MembershipService" value="Internal" />
 <!--<add key="MembershipService" value="ActiveDirectory" />
```

After this config , I try to login with windows user for example administrator , I got error your username or password incorrect .

Anybody can told me what's my wrong operation ?

Comment: I don't think you'll find WindowsAuth and Internal Membership a useful combination.  I'd suggest you use Cookies auth and Internal membership OR Windows auth + Active Directory.

Comment: after many search , I agree with you.